Relatively prime polynomials in the Euclidean domain $F[x]$ (Understanding Proof from Dummit & Foote)
I have been reading section 9.5, Proposition 16 in Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra on page 313. Here is the proposition and the proof, where $F$ is a field:

Proposition 16. Let $g(x)$ be a nonconstant element of $F[x]$ and let $$g(x) = f_1(x)^{n_1} f_2(x)^{n_2} \cdots f_k(x)^{n_k}$$ be its factorization into irreducibles, where the $f_i(x)$ are distinct. Then we have the following isomorphism of rings: $$F[x]/(g(x)) \cong F[x]/(f_1(x)^{n_1}) \times F[x]/(f_2(x)^{n_2}) \times \cdots \times F[x]/(f_k(x)^{n_k}).$$
Proof: This follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since the ideals $(f_i(x)^{n_i})$ and $(f_j(x)^{n_j})$ are comaximal if $f_i(x)$ and $f_j(x)$ are distinct (they are relatively prime in the Euclidean domain $F[x]$, hence the ideal generated by them is $F[x]$).

My question is: why are $\boldsymbol{f_i(x)}$ and $\boldsymbol{f_j(x)}$ relatively prime? For example, if we let $F = \mathbb{Q}$, $f_1(x) = x+1$, and $f_2(x) = 2x + 2$ ($f_2(x)$ is irreducible since $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}$), then $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are not relatively prime. Even if we assume that all the nonconstant polynomials are being grouped together in the factorization and the units are factored out (I guess they are one of the other $f_i(x)$ since it was never specified that they must be nonconstant), what about examples like $f_1(x) = 4x + 2 = 2(2x + 1)$ and $f_2(x) = 6x+8 = 2(3x + 4)$?

You may assume that $g$ is monic (since you only care about the ideal it generates) and then factorize it into monic polynomials.

They mean nonassociate irreducibles, which is equivalent to "distinct" if they are assumed monic (i.e. unit normalized). $\ \ $

The hypothesis is that the $f_i(x)$ are distinct irreducibles, and here "distinct" means up to multiplication by units. This is the same thing you have to do to state uniqueness of prime factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$; we don't want to think of, say, $6 = 2 \times 3 = (-2) \times (-3)$ as different factorizations, so over $\mathbb{Z}$ we have to say that $2, -2$ resp. $3, -3$ are "essentially the same prime" (formally the term is "associated" or something) because they are related by multiplication by the only nontrivial unit here, which is $-1$.
So $f_1(x) = x + 1, f_2(x) = 2x + 2$ is not a valid irreducible factorization because they aren't distinct. The irreducible factorization in this case would be $g(x) = 2 (x + 1)^2$, so $f_1(x) = x + 1, n_1 = 2$.
This actually means that Dummit and Foote's statement of what irreducible factorization looks like is incorrect; in this case if $\sqrt{2}$ isn't in the base field it is actually not possible to write $g$ as the square of an irreducible polynomial. They need to either specify an additional unit multiplication at the beginning or (my preferred approach) restrict to monic polynomials and monic irreducibles throughout.
$f_1(x) = 2(2x + 1)$ and $f_2(x) = 2(3x + 4)$ is not an issue; those are relatively prime. As you already said, $2$ is a unit!
